# POWERSHELL -lt not working

Tags: powershell

When importing a CSV in a  Powershell script then the less than -lt parameter does not function.
    EVERYTHING is imported in $fileName1 i.e. more than 21
    I need ONLY Volume with less than 21 to be imported in $fileName1

```
    Volume: \\SERVER1\VOL1
    % Free: 6%
    MB FREE: 6

    Volume: \\SERVER2\SYS
    % Free : 13%
    MB FREE: 13

    Volume: \\SERVER3\SYS
    % Free: 13%
    MB FREE: 13

    Volume: \\SERVER4\VOL1
    % Free: 16%
    MB FREE: 16

    Volume: \\SERVER5\VOL1
    % Free: 22%
    MB FREE: 22

    Volume: \\SERVER6\VOL1
    % Free: 35%
    MB FREE: 35


    # Date-Time to be appended in files
    $datestring = (Get-Date).ToString("s").Replace(":","-")

    # Files to be used
    $fileName0 = "C:\MONITORING\ALLVOLUMES\ALLVOLUMES.CSV"
    $fileName1 = "C:\MONITORING\ALLVOLUMES\ALERT\ALERTVOLUMES_$datestring.txt"
    $fileName3 = "C:\MONITORING\ALLVOLUMES\TRACKING\TRACKINGVOLUMES_$datestring.txt"

    import-csv $fileName0 | where-object {$_."MB Free" -lt 21} | Format-list >> $fileName1


Volume;Size(MB);Used(MB);Free (MB);% Free;MB FREE 
\\SERVER1\VOL1;1,549,818;1,500,335;49,483;3%;3
\\SERVER2\VOL1;1,020,950;977,259;43,691;4%;4
\\SERVER3\VOL1;1,123,047;1,051,394;71,653;6%;6
\\SERVER1\SYS;17,349;15,068;2,279;13%;13
\\SERVER2\SYS;17,349;14,807;2,177;13%;13
\\SERVER4\VOL1;784,091;648,436;125,846;16%;16
\\SERVER5\VOL1;207,061;160,487;46,440;22%;22
```

Comment: Show sample data of csv before import

Comment: That file says the first volume has 49,000 `Free Space(MB)`, 3 `% free` and 3 `MB FREE`. Your `MB FREE` column appears to contain percent, not megabytes. ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: 3  MB FREE is a number and it does represent a percentage without %

Comment: I have a list of Volumes and I need to filter all volumes which have less than 21% of free space to a file "$fileName1". but there is NO filter being done: ALL Volumes go to file "$fileName1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space in the headers for `"MB FREE "`. This is causing the filter to not be applied.

Either update the csv file to remove the extra space in the header or update the filter to include the space.

```
Where-Object { [int]$_."MB Free " -lt 21}
```

As mentioned in [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40391266/5233410) you also need to take into consideration that the values imported from the csv file will be imported as strings. As such you will have to cast the filtered property to an integer in order to make the `-lt` comparison valid. Other wise as mentioned you will be comparing string values as apposed to numeric values.

Using the following sample data (No extra white spaces)

```
Volume;Size(MB);Used(MB);Free (MB);% Free;MB FREE
\\SERVER1\VOL1;1,549,818;1,500,335;49,483;3%;3
\\SERVER2\VOL1;1,020,950;977,259;43,691;4%;4
\\SERVER3\VOL1;1,123,047;1,051,394;71,653;6%;6
\\SERVER1\SYS;17,349;15,068;2,279;13%;13
\\SERVER2\SYS;17,349;14,807;2,177;13%;13
\\SERVER4\VOL1;784,091;648,436;125,846;16%;16
\\SERVER5\VOL1;207,061;160,487;46,440;22%;22
```

And script with the appropriate delimiter set to `;`

```
Import-Csv $fileName0 -Delimiter ';' | Where-Object { [int]$_."MB Free" -lt 21} | Format-List -Property "Volume","Free (MB)","% FREE"
```

The following output was displayed

```
Volume    : \\SERVER1\VOL1
Free (MB) : 49,483
% Free    : 3%

Volume    : \\SERVER2\VOL1
Free (MB) : 43,691
% Free    : 4%

Volume    : \\SERVER3\VOL1
Free (MB) : 71,653
% Free    : 6%

Volume    : \\SERVER1\SYS
Free (MB) : 2,279
% Free    : 13%

Volume    : \\SERVER2\SYS
Free (MB) : 2,177
% Free    : 13%

Volume    : \\SERVER4\VOL1
Free (MB) : 125,846
% Free    : 16%
```

Comment: You should also point out that  the delimiteris needed (which you show) but is missing.

Comment: @user270488 `Where-Object { [int]$_."MB Free " -lt 21}`

Answer (score 2):

<sup>With the benefit of hindsight: The OP had *two types* of problems:

- *incidental* problems: a missing a trailing space in the column name; also, needing to change the default delimiter with `-Delimiter ';'`.

- a *fundamental conceptual* problem: applying `-lt` to *string* operands and expecting *numeric* comparison.

[Nkosi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40391854/45375) addresses all problems, but *this* answer provides a ***detailed explanation* of the *conceptual* problem**.</sup>

**tl;dr**

Cast the property to `[int]` (or a different numeric type, as appropriate):

```
import-csv $fileName0 | where-object {[int] $_."MB Free" -lt 21}
```

---

In the absence of a type-annotation header line (as `Export-Csv` adds by default), **`Import-Csv` by default does not perform any implicit *type conversions* for you - everything is imported as a `[string]`.**

For instance, if the `MB Free` column contains value `3`, it becomes a *string* property, and therefore `-lt` performs *lexical* (alphabetic) comparison, which is not the same as *numerical* comparison.

```
'3' -lt 21         # $false - !! LEXICAL comparison, because the LHS is a *string*
[int] '3' -lt 21   # $true - numerical comparison forced by cast
```

Therefore, you need to *cast* the properties of the objects representing the imported CSV rows to the desired numeric data type for the `-lt` operator to perform numeric comparisons.

Comment: but `"35" -lt 21` is $false, so even if it's doing lexical comparison it should not be getting past the filter, right? Nothing should be included, rather than everything being included.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Good point, though my answers definitely addresses _one_ problem. We don't know the specific input yet, but one possible explanation for the output is that the input may contain space-prefixed values,  e.g.,  
`"<space>35" -lt 21` yields `$true`.

Comment: @mklement0, update your post with the additional information from my findings and I'll remove my post.

Comment: @Nkosi: Thanks for offering, but I think the division of labor between our posts is fine now, especially now that you've linked to mine: your post focuses on the OP's specific problems, while mine focuses on the conceptual issue.